# how to include directions in iframe

Tags: google-maps

I have the following form:

```
<form method="get" action="http://maps.google.com/maps" target="_blank">
    <select name="daddr">
        <option selected value="Bovetstrasse 1, 3012 Bern, Switzerland">Missione (a Berna)</option>
        <option value="">Zollikofen</option>
        <option value="">B&uuml;mpliz</option>
        <option value="">Ostermundigen</option>
        <option value="">M&uuml;nsingen</option>
        <option value="">Konolfingen</option>
        <option value="">Worb</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="saddr" maxlength="255" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="hl" value="it">
    <input type="hidden" name="z" value="15">
    <input type="hidden" name="t" value="m">
    <input type="hidden" name="layer" value="t">
    <input type="hidden" name="doflg" value="ptk">
    <!--input type="hidden" name="output" value="embed"-->
    <button type="submit">Guidami</button>
    <p class="Didascalia">Powered by Google</p>
</form>
```

It opens a new window with the map and the directions on the left side as usual.

What I would like to do is to open this content in an iframe that I have in the same page **but**

- if I symply change the target to the iframe name, I get an error (This content cannot be displayed in a frame. To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.)
- if I also un-comment the `output=embed` parameter, then only the map is shown with the route but no listing of directions

Does any-one know how to do this?

Comment: Yes. The better way to do this is to use the Google Maps API rather than an embedded iframe from maps.google.com. The API was designed for exactly this purpose: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Comment: Thanks for the link, very useful. But I wanted to avoid javascript... if it is not possible to use maps.google.com directly then I prefer to have the job done on the server (via php) but it is a bit too "advanced" for my know-how